# Define initial state for each object in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I've got a list of objects inside a div, in which I have a clickable button similar to "like" from Facebook. If it's not liked it's white, and if it's liked it changes to black. The process is reversible. I have a store(and therefore actions) to keep the objects I like. When I click the button, the add/remove functions are working properly; However, when I refresh the page, even though the objects are still kept, the button of the liked objects won't appear black as they should. How can I set an initial state for each object to "recognize" the color it should be? I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: You can use `getInitialState` to get data from wherever you store it then return it to `render`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing the state of the object is stored somewhere (in the server, probably).

What you can do is,

```
componentDidMount() {

 //do an ajax GET request and extract like property out of the object like this:
 var o1 = JSON.parse(res.text)
 var liked = o1.liked //boolean

this.setState({isLiked: liked})
}

toggleLike() {

var {isLiked} = this.state

//do a POST req and toggle it to !isLiked

//and if it's a success, then 

this.setState({isLiked: !isLiked});

}

render() {

return(
<LikeButton onClick={this.toggleLike} />
)

}
```

Hope this helped, let me know if you have any doubts.